# Why do cells in meristematic tissues lack vacuoles?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, tissue

Cells located in meristematic cells in plants lack vacuoles. However, this contradicts with the fact that plant cells have large vacuoles to store water and keep the plant in an upright position. I would also like to add that meristematic tissues are generally found in roots and stems of plants. Finally, I would like to ask why do meristems lack vacuoles?

#### Sources

1. *Turgor pressure exerted by the vacuole is also essential in supporting plants in an upright position*: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuole)
2. *Apical mertisem is present at the growing tips of stems and roots and increases the length of the stem and the root. The girth of the stem or root increases due to lateral mertisem (cambium)*: [Science for Class 9 by National Council of Educational Research & Training, page number 69](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?iesc1=6-15)
3. *Cells of meristematic tissue are very active, they have dense cytoplasm, thin cellulose walls and prominent nuclei. They lack vacuoles*: [Science for Class 9 by National Council of Educational Research & Training, page number 70](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?iesc1=6-15)

Comment: Please do not edit the title to "answered", please accept the answer.

Comment: @Chris Well, I need to wait sixteen more hours to do that. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't looked at the times :-) It would be good if you could do it, then it is marked as answered and accepted on the starting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meristematic tissues or meristems contain cells which can rapidly divide or reproduce and is responsible for the overall growth of the plant. Apical meristems and lateral meristems are found in the roots and stems of the plants. Please note that the whole stem or root is not laded with these tissues. Plant cells usually have a large central vacuole which applies turgor pressure to keep the plant upright, as mentioned in one of your sources.

The tips do not require to be very stiff and straight. So, a central vacuole is just not required. Also, meristematic cells grow various organelles as they mature.